# How can I make voice call/How can I identify call using AT commands in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, modem, at-command

How can I make voice call/How can I identify call using AT commands in visual basic?
I am attempting to call a modem using a local modem connected via USB. Programming language is VB.NET and I am using the SerialPort control to talk to the modem.
to call and send a voice I try many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start voice calls with AT command `ATD12345678;` and (circuit switched) data calls with `ATD12345678` (for phone number 12345678).

If you have not worked with AT commands before, by all means read the V.250 specification (linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/at-command/info). It will teach you all you need to get started using AT commands correctly.

Comment: This is a lame answer to a lame question. It shows up in search results but it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

To receive caller id, you should write AT+CLCC on modem ringing.

```
RING

RING
AT+CLCC
+CLCC: 1,1,4,0,0,"+7281233445566",145

OK
```